# Error 'The requested URL returned error: 403' while pushing a GIT repo

Tags: linux, git, github, github-actions, gitlab-ci

I was trying to push a GIT repository to Github from my AWS server using HTTPS URL method. I am gettting following error;

```
remote: Permission to user1/project1.git denied to user1.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user1/project1.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Any idea?

I was trying to push my local respository to Github. I tried to create a new personal auth token from developer settings and tried again. But the error was still there. I am able to setup SSH successfully but the issue is still there with HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you clone your repository using the HTTPS protocol and when you do a push, you don't have HTTPS credential helpers defined in your local git config.

Check you git config:

```bash
git config --global --list
```

You should see something like this:

```bash
user.name=<Your Name>
user.email=<your_email@example.com>
credential.https://github.com.helper=
credential.https://github.com.helper=!/usr/local/bin/gh auth git-credential
credential.https://gist.github.com.helper=
credential.https://gist.github.com.helper=!/usr/local/bin/gh auth git-credential
```

Using this configuration you are able to clone and push using HTTPs protocol.

But, how do I configure this for my local git config?

You must install **GH CLI** on your system and auth on your GitHub account using a github token:

- https://github.com/cli/cli/

Another way to do this without using the GH CLI to define credential helpers is to define your github token in the remote git URL as follows.

Get remote URL:

```bash
git remote -v
```

Update remote URL with **github token**:

```bash
git remote set-url origin https://<github-token>@github.com/user1/project1.git
```

By doing this you can push to your git repository.

**NOTE: This last option is something possible to do, but it is not safe much less recommended, if you follow this path, be careful and try to provide / configure the correct and secure authentication process as soon as possible.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: You should use a credential helper instead of putting the token in the URL.  Storing the token in the URL is not a secure method of storing credentials, and it should not be recommended to users without that caveat.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that, I really missed saying that this is possible but not safe or recommended, thanks again @bk2204.